# Como importar arquivo de registros no asp.net mvc com entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida e não sei como estruturar a minha necessidade..

Preciso importar/exportar um arquivo com registros, e dependendo cada registro será de uma tabela diferente, com suas referências e etc.. Quais formatos de arquivo é o ideal? .csv, xls, e etc..

No arquivo separo cada item com delimitador ou com cabeçalho especifico para cada item? Qual melhor forma?

Qual a melhor forma de criar esse layout de arquivo e importar/exportar? Por enquanto não tenho ideia de como fazer..

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/).

Veja alguns exemplos de como utilizá-lo

Dados delimitados por virgula

```
1732,Juan Perez,435.00,11-05-2002
554,Pedro Gomez,12342.30,06-02-2004
112,Ramiro Politti,0.00,01-02-2000
924,Pablo Ramirez,3321.30,24-11-2002
```

Classe de mapeamento

```
using FileHelpers;

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public int CustId;

    public string Name;

    public decimal Balance;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime AddedDate;

}
```

Lendo e escrevendo com o `FileHelpers`

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();

// To Read Use:
var result = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt");
// result is now an array of Customer

// To Write Use:
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", result);
```

Exibindo o resultado

```
foreach (Customer cust in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Info:");
    Console.WriteLine(cust.Name + " - " +
                      cust.AddedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"));
}
```

Se não me engano a versão mais nova já dá suporte a propriedades também.